# Object parent key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `AngularJS` to display some data on a table, for that I'm making use of `ng-repeat` which takes an object and displays the values of the properties of it in the table cells.

The object structure is like this:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  "containerKey" : {
        "parentKey" : {
           "childKey1" : "value",
           "childKey2" : "value",
           "childKey3" : "value
        }
  }
}
```

The ng-repeat shows a table

```
<table ng-repeat="key in containerKey">
   <tr>
    <!-- This should display the value of the key (in my case it is the name of a day in the week, but it displayed the entire object inside key.parentKey, which is expected -->
    <th id="day">{{ key.parentKey }}</th> <!-- I would like for this to show the value of the key, in my case that would be the name of the day, like "monday" -->

   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>{{ parentKey.childKey1 }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>{{ parentKey.childKey2 }}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>{{ parentKey.childKey3 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How would I go about showing only the key value of the parentKey in the table cell? Consider that I'm using `ng-repeat` to show multiple rows and each of this rows contain the `ng-repeat` that contains the days (parentKey).

To clarify:

I would like the `<th>` element with `id="day"` to show the text of the `parentKey` key. The `th` element's content would be `parentKey` (the string parentKey), literally, instead of the value of `parentKey`.

Comment: Please clarify the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried altering your ng-repeat to use the object notation:

```
<table ng-repeat="(key, value) in containerKey">
```

You should have access to the key then.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your code you are trying to use ng-repeat over an object. ng-repeat should iterate over arrays.

Considerating `containerKey` is an array of `parentKey`, this may works:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in containerKey">
        <th>{{key}}</th>
        <tr>{{value.childKey1}}</tr>
        <tr>{{value.childKey2}}</tr>
        <tr>{{value.childKey3}}</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Correct, I'm upvoting you because the first answer was given by rrd so I'm going to give him the correct answer, on a timely basis! Thanks!